# AZURE　SQL へ Access で接続したときのクエリの漢字の扱い

Tags: sql, azure, ms-access, sql-azure

```
select 氏名 from 顧客基本情報 where 氏名 = '漢字'
```

とすると結果が０件になります。

AZURE SQL管理サイトで

```
select 氏名 from 顧客基本情報 where 氏名 = N'漢字'
```

のように漢字の前にNをつけると結果が返ってくるのですが
Access側のクエリでは構文エラーとなります。

同じくAccess側のクエリで

```
select 氏名 from 顧客基本情報 where 氏名 = strconv('漢字',64);
```

としても結果は０件となります。

Access側のクエリで漢字データの検索方法をご存知の方教えてください。
よろしく願いします。

Comment: 「select [氏名] from [顧客基本情報] where [氏名] = strconv('漢字',64);」とするとどうなりますでしょうか。

Comment: heliac2001 様
回答ありがとうございます。
select [氏名] from [顧客基本情報] where [氏名] = strconv('漢字',64);
としても結果は０件となります。
原因がわかりましたので、下段の回答へのコメントします。

Answer (score 3):

どのようにAccessで接続したかわかりませんが、ODBCデータソースからリンクテーブル経由でクエリを実行した限りでは問題なく取得できました。

参考になるかわかりませんが、詳細を書いておきます。

## SQL Azure

- 照合順序 - Japanese_CI_AI

## 接続クライアント

- Windows 8.1
- Ms Access 2013

### ODBC データソース

- プロバイダ SQL Server Native Client 11.0  
  Native Clientであれば問題ないと思います。
- `Change the default database to:`を目的のデータベースに変更した以外は標準のまま
  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### テーブル

Azure 管理ポータル上で以下のsqlで作成

```
create table 顧客基本情報 (id int primary key, 氏名 nvarchar(32))
```

詳細は以下の通り

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### SQL

```
select 氏名
FROM dbo_顧客基本情報
where 氏名='漢字'
```

[image: access1]
[image: access2]

Comment: flied onion様
回答ありがとうございます。
参考に頂いた•照合順序 - Japanese_CI_AIの情報が原因解明につながりました。
デフォルトではSQL_Latin_General_CP1_CI_ASのため検索時に合致しなかったようです。
ちなみに、Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Accessで250,000以上のデータを変換する場合は、スケールがBasicではNGでした。
それがわからず、照合順序を変えるのに、1日かかってしまいました。

Comment: @YasushiJin さん、解決されたようでよかったです。デフォルトがJapaneseではないので見落としがちですよね。スケールの情報ありがとうございます。参考にさせてもらいます。